# Where does image_picker store images?

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

This is just a general question as to how the image_picker plugin works. When I select an image from the device gallery, the path is something like this: "*tmp/image_picker*.jpg". This is obviously not the original path of the image on the device. Does image_picker make a copy of the image? If so, where is it stored? Is it stored in the app data?

Maybe someone could point me to a white paper that explains all of this.

When I take a picture using the camera and image_picker the filename has the similar tmp path. The image can be reloaded by my app, but the image is not available in the device gallery. I understand that there are plugins to save the image to the gallery, but I would like to know how to delete the extra images from the tmp folder.

Comment: Can you explain your problem and what you trying to achieve?

Comment: @SandeepSharma Thanks for taking the time to respond.   I don't have a problem per se, but right now I'm just assuming how the plugin actually works. I'm trying to avoid multiple copies of images on a user's device or save the images in a more specific way. I can easily copy the images to the gallery, firebase storage, and to the application directory. How about answering these specific questions? How do I delete the tmp images created by image picker? Is there a plugin that grabs a reference to the image already on the device instead of copying it?

Comment: You can get the temp folder, and delete files in it.

var appDir = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
new Directory(appDir).delete(recursive: true);

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t1Cd.png)  & [link](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker).

> **Note:** Images and videos picked using the camera are saved to your application's local cache, and should therefore be expected to only be
> around temporarily. If you require your picked image to be stored
> permanently, it is your responsibility to move it to a more permanent
> location.

Also same for gallery images because every time `file_path` will different because the library will store image in cache / temporary storage.